# Unity: Bypass Ctrl+S in a custom Editor Window

Tags: unity

Is there a way to bypass <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> for Windows or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> for Apple default behaviour (save scene) in a custom editor window?

Comment: Maybe a script that is marked as [ExecuteInEditMode]? Not the best solution, since it will still trigger the default behaviour as well, but I don't think you can actually overwrite this (I've tried it before to bind save project to it).

Comment: @Athosvk I don't think it's possible either, but I'm still asking just in case I am wrong and someone knows how to do the trick. Thanks for your comment anyway.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this post on Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/175931/perform-action-on-saveload-in-editor.html)? You can get a callback just before the scene is saved, and modify the set of content that gets written.